# Loop through Multiple Database table and Insert into Temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Edit for better clarification.

I have a table created with two columns around 60 rows

```
----SiteDboTable---
SELECT 
    [SiteName]
    , CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Wind' THEN CONCAT('[YYY].[dbo].', '[', Replace(Translate([SiteName], ' -\','???'),'?',''), 'Turbine]')
        ELSE  CONCAT('[YYY].[dbo].', '[', Replace(Translate([SiteName], ' -\','???'),'?',''), 'Inverter]') 
        END AS dboName
FROM [XXX].[dbo].[Site]
Order By SiteName
```

Table output:

```
SiteName  dboName
site1     [YYY].[dbo].[site1Inverter] 
....      .....
....      .....
site4     [YYY].[dbo].[site4Inverter]
..n..     ..n..
```

I want to loop through each row of `SiteDboTable` and insert each rows data into `HLEEtmp_table`

Using `SiteDboTable`table above, I want to use the two columns (`SiteName`, `dboName`) each as a variable. Each variable will be updated/changed in the script below. So that when I run `HLEEtmp_table` it is changing the `SiteName` and `FROM` statement each time. Then the data from each iteration of ``HLEEtmp_table``` iteration, this data will be inputted into another table to store all the data.

```
---HLEEtmp_table---
'SELECT 
    dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, DataTimeStamp), 0) AS DataTimeStamp
    ,'+@SiteName+' AS Site 
    , DeviceID
    , AVG([RealPowerAC]) AS RealPowerAC_MEAN
FROM'+@TableName+' WHERE DataTimeStamp >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())
GROUP BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, DataTimeStamp), 0)
    , datepart(hour,DataTimeStamp)
    , [DeviceID];'
```

Below is what I was trying. Not sure if this is the correct approach. A cursor approach might not work, I think.

Any Ideas or help would be appreciated.

First, I am creating my two temp tables needed for my data table to `INSERT` into and my table containing my FROM statement schemas.

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#HLEEtmp_table') IS NOT NULL )
 DROP TABLE #HLEEtmp_table;
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SiteDboTable') IS NOT NULL )
 DROP TABLE #SiteDboTable;
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#HLEEtmp_table2') IS NOT NULL )
 DROP TABLE #HLEEtmp_table2;
 
--Create Temp Table #HLEEtmp_table; this table will hold the data I need---------
CREATE TABLE #HLEEtmp_table (
    DataTimeStamp VARCHAR(50),
    Site VARCHAR(50),
    DeviceID VARCHAR(50),
    RealPowerAC_MEAN VARCHAR(50)    
)
----------------------------------------------------------
/*Create Temp Table #SiteDboTable: 
    - This table will list of all [DB].[dbo].[table] names in column [AssetName]
    - #SiteDboTable will create a table with 60 rows and 2 columns.
    - From #SiteDboTable: need [Site] column and [dboName] column for insert into #HLEEtmp_table 
    - #SiteDboTable.[Site] = #HLEEtmp_table.[Site]
    - #SiteDboTable.[dboName] will be #HLEEtmp_table FROM statement: FROM #SiteDboTable.[dboName] "i.e.  [XXX].[dbo].[AVInverter]"*/

SELECT 
    [SiteName]
    , CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Wind' THEN CONCAT('[XXX].[dbo].', '[', Replace(Translate([SiteName], ' -\','???'),'?',''), 'Turbine]')
        ELSE  CONCAT('[XXX].[dbo].', '[', Replace(Translate([SiteName], ' -\','???'),'?',''), 'Inverter]') 
        END AS dboName
INTO #SiteDboTable
FROM [YYY].[dbo].[Site]
Order By SiteName
```

With the data from Temp Table `#SiteDboTable`, I want to use `#SiteDboTable` columns in the below table `#HLEEtmp_table2`. Pull my data from `#HLEEtmp_table2` and `INSERT` into my temp data table `#HLEEtmp_table`.

```
---------------------------------
--INSERT INTO #HLEEtmp_table VALUES ('DataTimeStamp','Site','DeviceID','RealPowerAC_MEAN')

DECLARE @TableCount int 
DECLARE @SiteName varchar(50) 
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
DECLARE @TableName varchar(256)

SELECT @TableCount = COUNT(1) from #SiteDboTable

WHILE @TableCount > 0 
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1 @SiteName = SiteName from #SiteDboTable ORDER BY SiteName
    SELECT @SQL = '
                    SELECT 
                      dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, DataTimeStamp), 0) AS DataTimeStamp
                      ,'+@SiteName+' AS Site 
                      , DeviceID
                      , AVG([RealPowerAC]) AS RealPowerAC_MEAN
                    INTO #HLEEtmp_table2
                    FROM
                         '+@TableName+'
                    WHERE
                      DataTimeStamp >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())
                    GROUP BY
                      dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, DataTimeStamp), 0)
                      , datepart(hour,DataTimeStamp)
                      , [DeviceID];
                      
                    -- Drop the Primary Key Column from the temp table  
                    -- Alter Table #HLEEtmp_table2 Drop Column [PrimaryKeyColumn]

                    -- Insert that into your other big table
                    Insert Into #HLEEtmp_table
                        Select * From #HLEEtmp_table2

                    -- Drop the temp table you created
                    Drop Table #HLEEtmp_table2
                    '
    
    EXEC (@SQL)
    
    DELETE #SiteDboTable WHERE dboName = @TableName
    SELECT @SiteName = COUNT(1) from #SiteDboTable
    
END
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a cursor

Comment: Why is this here `Alter Table #HLEEtmp_table2 Drop Column [PrimaryKeyColumn]`? There's no `PrimaryKey` column in the select-into statement that creates and populates the temp table.

Comment: What does "it is not inserting my data into #HLEEtmp_table2" mean? Do you get any error messages or it just does not work?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for noticing that, I meant to pull it out, was testing different ways and accidentally left it in. And Yes, you are correct. Will edit to remove.

Comment: @Alex when I search my temp table ````#select * from #HLEEtmp_table2``` I get error ```Invalid object name '#HLEEtmp_table2'``` as though it is not creating the temp table to insert data into.

Comment: @nbk No I have not and not familiar with that. will need to look into it.

Comment: Are you running the same code that you posted in your question?

In any case: First of all read up on how temp tables work. There is a concept called "scope". `EXEC (@SQL)` creates a new scope, which means temp tables created inside it will not be visible to the outside.

Comment: @Alex OP's code seems ok, as they have created a temptable on the main scope and then they are filling it from inside scopes.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis - I am confused by this statement "I search my temp table ````#select * from #HLEEtmp_table2``` I get error Invalid object name '#HLEEtmp_table2' "

Comment: @Alex yes, #2 dies when the exec(@SQL) ends. However, the original # still lives, and is filled with the data #2 had

Answer (score 0):

if I where I could have added

```
Print (@SQL)
EXEC (@SQL)
```

and that should give me the dynamic SQL which you are executing and that way it will be easy to troubleshoot .

HTH